# Accelerate intel CORE i7 processor by OpenCL

Tags: opencl, cpu, intel, hpc, amd-gpu

Let suppose that I have a server machine without any monitor to it and there is an algorithm running on it (process). Can I increase the performance of the algorithm by using the OpenCL to use the graphical part of the CPU? Or what does the operation system use that part of the CPU for, when there is no monitor?

In the case of AMD (APU) is similar.

What do you think, how much performance increase can I achieve?

[image]

If there is no monitor, the graphics part can be used for anything else?

I would like collect the advantages and disadvantages.

EDIT: add imagine for my first comment

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Whether or not you can use the IGPU that's part of the CPU package in headless mode mostly depends on 2 things; the hardware certainly doesn't care:

  1. Whether the IGPU is enabled in the machine's firmware (BIOS/UEFI)
  2. Whether your driver stack/OS lets you do this.
- "What do you think, how much performance increase can I achieve?" - This depends on your workload and how fast your CPU and GPU are. It's well documented what kinds of workloads translate well to GPUs. For a **very** rough estimate at an upper bound of what you can do, compare FLOPS values for the CPU and GPU parts of your hardware.

Comment: For example, my "simple" laptop has the following CPU:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz with Intel HD Graphics 5500

Comment: Please take a look at my second image in the main post. You can see there are several computation units in the Intel CPU which is mostly is supposed to be used by the screen. Let me suppose that I have a server, I turn off the screen. Do these units are used?  When I changed to my old NVIDIA to this VGA controller and my computation became 1000 times faster. (Secondary points, but still there is no big support in std c++ threads, boost already supports OpenCL, but according to my measurements it is not faster.)

Comment: So, I still don't know whether is it promising to build a server service on OpenCL and use that computation unit in case of old industrial machines?